# Experiences using "FEAN" stack for web application development?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I have recently been looking into technology stacks that I could possible use for a new web application I am considering developing for my final year project.

The FEAN stack or Firebase, Express, AngularJS and Node.js stack has recently caught my eye and I was wondering how other developers found using this technology stack? And if there was any opinions/thoughts/recommendations you might have before I start?

I know this is just a variation of the MEAN stack but looking into Firebase's user authentication services I think it could be a better suite for my application.

Comment: whoever downvoted this question, please explain why.

Comment: This is opinion-based and thus not a good fit for here. Other than that it also asks that we recommend a tool which is a second reason for it not being a good fit. As you can see, the 2 answers are already vastly different.

Comment: ok, that will be useful to OP in case his question gets deleted and he wants to ask another. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the FEAN stack is absolutely feasible. Firebase can indeed replace MongoDB entirely. It depends on your needs of course.

The 'F' in FEAN actually gives you two options: Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore. There are significant differences between the two, so I recommend studying up on those. They will impact performance (and cost, down the line, if you switch to a paid plan). At the risk of oversimplifying, Realtime DB is relatively simple and limited, whereas Firestore attempts to emulate MongoDB's sophisticated querying language and organization into collections.

**More resources:**

1) https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore

2) https://savvyapps.com/blog/firebase-realtime-database-vs-cloud-firestore-for-your-app

Also note that MongoDB and Firebase DBs are not mutually exclusive.

In one of my apps, for example, I am using both, side-by-side. I have a Mongo Cloud Atlas deployment, and make API calls to it via Firebase Functions. So the E and N part of your stack could both be handled by Firebase Functions. Watch their official video for more details: [Node.js apps on Firebase Hosting Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=268s).

If you want to go the server-less architecture route, the following stack was surprisingly easy to set up:

```
F: Firebase Cloud Firestore OR Firebase Realtime Database
E: Express app hosted on Firebase Functions
A: Angular front-end using AngularFire2 package
N: Node app hosted on Firebase Functions
```

I think you'll find that all these components integrate together nicely.

In my case, I'm running an MFEAN stack. I cache the processed results of my Mongo query in my Realtime Database. This way, I don't have to call my MongoDB over and over for common requests. I can serve those from my Firebase Realtime DB instead, which is crazy fast.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with standards (W3C or de facto standards), especially starting out. Start out with the LAMP stack - Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

If you do go with Firebase, Express/Angular/Node is not necessary. Firebase Hosting will serve files for you. Firebase Authentication enables authentication and authorization. Firebase Firestore is your database if you need accounting, or other datastore needs.

In any case, use standards based JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.